# cache api data using sw-toolbox

Tags: caching, service-worker, sw-toolbox

I am using sw-toolbox to cache all the resources. However, I am not able to figure out how to cache api response data. I could use indexDb or internal storage for the same. Just curious to know, can I just cache it using service worker?

I tried using the below code but it didn't work.

```
importScripts('bower_components/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js'); 
toolbox.options.debug = true;

toolbox.precache(['/','/main.js',
               '/main.css']);

toolbox.router.get('/', toolbox.fastest);
toolbox.router.get(/googleapis/, toolbox.fastest);
toolbox.router.get(/firebaseio/, toolbox.fastest);
```

So my fonts and Images are getting cached which hit the url googleapis, however request goes to firebaseio doesn't seem to work.
Is it possible to achieve what I am doing here?

Comment: What type of requests are going to `firebaseio`? Are they Web Sockets, or are they HTTP GET requests made via the Firebase REST API?

Comment: HTTP GET requests made via the Firebase REST API